# Seaborn tsplot subset of conditions

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have some data that I am plotting with `seaborn` using `tsplot` which looks fine.

I currently have 8 different categories possible for my "condition" input specified by a field `car_type` and I am wondering if I can use `seaborn` to call `tsplot` to only show a subset of these categories.

So I am hoping I can have one `csv` with data for each "condition" but create a plot using `seaborn` to only show a `tsplot` of *A*,*B*,*C* or *B*,*C* instead of showing all possible categories *A*,*B*,*C*,*D*,*E*,*F*,*G*,*H*.

I know I could create multiple `csv` for each comparison, but I am hoping that I can specify condition=[`car_type=A`, `car_type=B`] or something like that.

Comment: Please show us the plots and also how the dataframe looks like.

Comment: Let me rephrase to perhaps make this easier, is there a way to call tsplot on the Gamma data-set to only plot IPS and AG from the ROI category? Or would I have to create a whole new Gamma-2var dataset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to create another dataset, but rather only query the element you'd want to focus on as shown:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gammas = sns.load_dataset("gammas")    # Loading the gamma dataset
IPS = gammas.query("ROI == 'IPS'")     # Selecting subset of rows of ROI category 
AG = gammas.query("ROI == 'AG'")

f, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)

sns.tsplot(data=IPS, time="timepoint", unit="subject",
           condition="ROI", value="BOLD signal", ci=[68, 95], ax=ax[0])

sns.tsplot(data=AG, time="timepoint", unit="subject",
           condition="ROI", value="BOLD signal",ci=[68, 95], ax=ax[1])
```